# Arduino SoftwareSerial corrupted output

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

Good afternoon,
I am trying to communicate through WiFi with ESP8266 module on Arduino. So far I have succeded to make my hardware setup and a very basic communication in between Arduino and ESP8266 module. I am using SoftwareSerial library to communicate, however the data outputs printed to the Serial seems quite corrupted, even though the module succesfully connects.

When I sent `AT+CWJAP="AndroidAP","52689785"` on Serial console, this is the output:

```
AT+CWJAP="AndroidAP","52689785"
AT+C⸮⸮P⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ѕ͉b⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ѕ⸮ɂ⸮⸮j
WIFI DISCONNQ(UH⸮WIFI CONNECTED
WHFI GOT IP

OK
```

Below is my full code, I communicate with ESP module through pins 10 and 11:

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial softSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   // Serial.setTimeout(30);
   softSerial.begin(115200);
   // softSerial.setTimeout(30);
   while(!Serial);
}

void loop()
{
   if (softSerial.available())
   {
      String message = softSerial.readString();
      Serial.print(message);
   }

   if (Serial.available())
   {
      String message = Serial.readString();
      Serial.print(message);
      softSerial.print(message);
   }
}
```

I would appreciate if you could show me the solution for a better communication in between Arduino and ESP module, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Most of the ESP8266 modules will be working better at 115200 baud rate.

The reason for gibberish output can be:

- either you may be viewing output at 9600 baud rate

[visit the link](http://www.teomaragakis.com/hardware/electronics/how-to-connect-an-esp8266-to-an-arduino-uno/)

Comment: But software serial **doesn't** work better at 115200 baud rate.